# Dyck path bijection

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The problem is as below:

**Prove that there is a bijection between Dyck paths from $(0, 0)$ to $(2n, 0)$ and $n$-tuples $(a_1, a_2, a_3, ... a_n)$ of integers $a_i \geq 2$ such that in the sequence $1a_1a_2...a_n1$, each $a_i$ divides the sum of its neighbors.**

Below is the progress we have made:

Let $D^n$ be the set of Dyck paths from $(0, 0)$ to $(2n, 0)$.
$$\text{Let }G^n=\bigg\{g = g_1g_2...g_n\ :\ g_i \in \mathbb{N},\ \sum_{i = 1}^n{g_i}=n,\ \sum_{i = 1}^n{g_i - 1}=0,\ \forall\ k < n \in \mathbb{N}, \sum_{i = 1}^k{g_i - 1} \ge 0\bigg\}$$
Let $S^n$ be the set of $n$-tuples $(a_1, a_2, a_3, ... a_n)$ of integers $a_i \geq 2$ such that in the sequence $1a_1a_2...a_n1$, each $a_i$ divides the sum of its neighbors.
Define $g: D^n \longrightarrow G^n, g(d) = b_1b_2...b_n$, where $b_i$ is the number of times path $d$ moves up between the $(i-1)$th and the $i$th time the path moves down. Note that $b_1$ is the number of times the path moves up before the first time it moves down.
$$\text{Define } h: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow \mathbb{N}, h(a, b) = \begin{cases}
b - a & b > a\\
\lceil\frac{a}{b}\rceil \cdot b - a & b \leq a
\end{cases}$$
Define $f : G^n \longrightarrow S^n$. Note that while not part of $f(d)$, if used, $s_{-1} = 0$ and $s_0=1$.
        $$f(v) = (s_1, s_2, s_3, ... s_n), s_i = h(s_{i - 2}, s_{i - 1})+s_{i-1}\cdot v_i$$

Example: 
Consider the example of the following Dyck path: $\{(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 1), (6, 0)\}$.
We begin by calculating $v = g(d)$ to be $(2, 1, 0)$, since the path moves upwards twice before it moves down first, then it moves up once before moving down again, and ends by moving down without moving up at all. We can see that $\sum v_i = 3 = n$ and that $\sum v_i - 1 = 0$, with every sum along the way non-negative as well, confirming that $v \in G^3$.
Then we begin calculating $s = f(v)$ with $s_1 = h(s_{-1}, s_{0}) + s_{0} \cdot v_1 = h(0, 1) + v_1 = 1 + 2 = 3$. Then we calculate $s_2 = h(s_0, s_1) + s_1 \cdot v_2 = h(1, 3) + 3 \cdot 1 = 2 + 3 = 5$. Finally, we calculate $s_3 = h(s_1, s_2) + s_2 \cdot v_3 = h(3, 5) + 5 \cdot 0 = 2 + 0 = 2$. Therefore we have that the sequence is $13521$, with $(s_1, s_2, s_3) = (3, 5, 2)$

Now, the problem that I have is to prove that $f$ is onto. With the definition of $f$ and $s=(s_1, s_2, ..., s_n)$ known, it is easy to express $v_i =\frac{s_i - h(s_{i - 2}, s_{i-1})}{s_{i-1}}$.  However, I don't know how to prove that $v=(v_1, v_2, ..., v_n)$ $\in G$. That is, $v$ has to satisfy two properties:

$1. \sum_{i = 1}^n{v_i - 1}=0,$

$2. for \ all\ k < n \in \mathbb{N}, \sum_{i = 1}^k{v_i - 1} \ge 0$

Can anybody provide some help or give some hints? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a bijection described in _Combinatorial Theory Seminar Eindhoven University of Technology_ by van Lint, p. 26-7 ([link](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2FBFb0057319)). I will post an answer when I understand it.